# Android emulator for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, android, emulator

### I'm looking for an Android emulator for Windows.

#### Requirements:

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), with no nags or prompts
- Supports [windows](/questions/tagged/windows)
- Uses [android](/questions/tagged/android) version 4.3 or higher
- Option to manually change the screen orientation with a button or shortcut (so I don't have to physically turn my laptop 90 degrees)
- Option to manually change screen resolution
- Original and clean android interface, as little additions as possible
- Google Play and other Google apps included, or option to install them later without too much hassle
- Should be able to run most apps without problems or issues

#### Not required, but useful:

- Ability to automatically change the screen orientation, depending on the app currently used (like Bluestacks does)
- Ability to automatically change resolution to the maximum supported by the physical screen (in full-screen mode), or resize to the window (in windowed mode)
- [open-source](/questions/tagged/open-source)
- Ability to easily root Android

**I have already tried *[Bluestacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/)*** (is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis), but wants you to install sponsored apps from time to time unless you pay a monthly fee of €2,- -|- doesn't have the original android homescreen -|- can't change the resolution AFAIK -|- might not be free when the beta is over),
***[AndroVM](http://androvm.org/blog/)*** (last version is 4.1, isn't being maintained anymore, merged into Genymotion),
***[Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)*** (I got the virtual machine to work, and I managed to install Google Play with [this article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952), but installed apps crash the whole time, because the underlying framework is unstable. And now Genymotion won't launch *again*...),
***[Android-x86](http://www.android-x86.org/)*** (changing resolution is not an easy procedure, no idea how to change screen orientation if that's even possible) and
***[Windroy](http://www.socketeq.com/)*** (doesn't include google play, can't run certain apps)

Comment: seems like bluestacks has just about everything you want, and really, it's not worth being picky about the home screen and sponsored apps. And, although it's not the easiest thing, you can without TOO much trouble change the resolution (just simple registry changing): http://hkdevtips.blogspot.com/2013/01/adjusting-screen-resolution-of-bluestack.html

Comment: Perhaps the Android SDK?

Comment: @Markasoftware It also worries me that Bluestacks will probably not be free anymore when the beta (which it has been in for quite a long time) is over, and then I will have to look for an alternative

Comment: well, the beta has been for years, and I don't see an end in sight, but good point. It's fine to use it for now, though

Comment: You could keep a watch on this kickstarter project. https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/mmv/console-os-dual-boot-android-remastered-for-the-pc. It is essentially Android installable on Windows

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ [ConsoleOS has been funded](http://consoleos.com/), and it sure looks like an interesting project, but it focuses primarily on dual-booting Windows and Android, whereas what I want is a virtual machine / emulator. If you were able to run it in a virtual machine (and who knows, perhaps it is a possibility, but even then I'd feel uncomfortable using an OS that was made for dual-booting), I would consider using it, but otherwise...
Thanks for the suggestion anyway, though! *(and yes, I know I'm replying to a more-than-a-year-old comment, but I just really wanted to post this comment)*

Comment: @nidunc THANKS - I completely forgot about that project! I might get it :) And I understand, although it probably is possible to run it in Virtualbox or the like, however you'll need to experiment, and that make take considerable time!! Your welcome, and thanks again for reminding me :D

Comment: NoxPlayer maybe?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Android-x86 + VirtualBox](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/)

- free and open-source
- Windows/Mac/Linux (including I believe Windows 8 although I haven't tried it personally)
- Uses [Android version 4.3](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list)
- Original and clean android interface, as little additions as possible
- Google Play included
- Should be able to play most apps without problems or issues
- to rotate screen, see [rotating the view for android x86 on VMWare](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18418117)

> Want to run Android on your PC? The Android-x86 Project has ported
> Android to the x86 platform from ARM. Android-x86 can be installed on
> netbooks with supported hardware, but you can also install Android in
> VirtualBox.
>
> Android can be run as just another virtual machine, like you would run
> a Windows or Linux virtual machine. This allows you to play with the
> Android interface and install apps in a full Android environment on
> your PC.
>
> Before you can get started, you’ll need both VirtualBox and an
> Android-x86 ISO to install inside VirtualBox.
>
> Install VirtualBox:
>
> - Download and install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) if you don’t
>   already have it installed.
> - Download an <s>[Android-x86 ISO](https://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list)</s> [Android-x86 ISO](https://www.android-x86.org/): You can find
>   the latest Android-x86 ISO files at <s>Google Code</s> their project site. Download the latest
>   one — <s>currently Android 4.2</s>.

[image]

Comment: Actually, there's also a 4.4 version of anroid-x86. The linked question about changing screen orientation doesn't work for me, no matter what I try, it won't turn.

Comment: I've tried that 4.3 variant lately. Works fine as long as you don't need to run rooted apps, but I was unable to get superuser/SuperSU working on it (which works by default with the 4.0 image btw). Not sure whether that's fixed with the 4.4 image, which is the next on my list to try out :) If you're crazy enough: There's at least a pre-rooted image on Mega linked from [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwwH6xBn4mg); I'm not sure whether to trust it, though :)

Answer (score 1):

How to run Android apps/LineageOS in Qemu

This is a replay to [similar](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/230269/is-it-possible-to-virtualize-android-on-an-x86-machine) question (moderators please move it there).

1. Run Qemu: `qemu-system-x86_64 -machine accel=kvm:tcg -net user -net nic -m 2G -vnc 127.0.0.1:74 -drive file=/path/to/hdd.img,format=qcow2 -cpu Opteron_G4`.
2. Run VNC: `vncviewer 127.0.0.1:5974`.
3. Install in VM: Debian, xfce4, weston, [waydroid](https://waydro.id).
4. Set framebuffer driver in /etc/X11/xorg.conf (`Device: "fb...?"`).
5. Disable GPU acceleration in Waydroid (Search for "site:waydro.id run waydroid in vm qemu" and add to /var/lib/waydroid/waydroid.conf `Parameters: ro. ...=...`, then run `waydroid upgrade -o`).
6. Run Waydroid: `WAYLAND_DISPLAY=wayland-1 waydroid first-launch`.

Unfortunately without KVM CPU acceleration (`accel=tcg -cpu max`) Weston crashes with "Segmentation fault". Probably GUI `virt-manager` can configure KVM properly.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this answer.  It states that it is a reply to a question on another SE site, and asks us moderators to move it there.  I may be mistaken, but I don't think we moderators have the ability to move answers across sites.  Can you post this answer on Android Enthusiasts SE as an answer to the intended question, please?

Comment: Offtopic: @moderators, unfortunately on [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com) for Tor Browser answers without registration wasn't available and in signing up process after solving Google captcha there was a red message stating that I can't create account.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Would you like me to use my account to post your answer on Android SE?  It will have to be under my account (I don't know of a way to migrate answers, only questions), but I will certainly make it clear the answer comes from you.  Also, would you like me to delete your answer on this site after I do that, or keep it here as well?