# Free android emulator for Windows that's lightweight and without any virtual box

Tags: android, emulator

Is there a simple lightweight (eats little RAM, takes little HD space) Windows desktop application that I can use, that runs just like an Android phone?

Related questions: [1](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6889/android-emulator-for-windows), [2](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37216/android-emulator-that-doesnt-use-vmware).

Comment: What do you mean by "without any virtual box"? As long as it does not require you to install https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads then it is OK? Are other virtual machine engines like VMware OK? To run Android on Windows a virtual machine engine will be needed, hidden or not.

Comment: Sorry I am a layperson with software. What I don't like about the VMWare option is that I have to install VMWare first (itself already not at all lightweight) and then in addition something else. I'd like a solution that's lightweight and doesn't require me to go through two installations.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has an [Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/).

I assume that by `without any virtual box` you mean that it doesn't have to be run inside an emulated OS, because obviously any emulator will be virtual in some way.

Comment: Tried installing but was unfortunately told that "This computer does not support the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, which requires a 64-bit Windows 8/8.1/10 Pro/Enterprise edition or Window Server 2012 or above and a computer that supports Hyper-V." I have 64-bit Windows 10, not sure if pro and not sure if my computer supports Hyper-V.

Comment: @KennyLJ Right click on the start button then system then see if "edition" is "windows 10 pro". Run cmd as administrator and type systeminfo and see at the end "Hyper-V Requirements".

Answer (score 1):

I will put my money on [MEmu - Android emulator](http://www.memuplay.com)

It is highly customizable, yet lightweight with elegant features:

Rich Features:

- Full Android experience with an elegant desktop
- Flexible customization (CPU, memory, resolution, device model, root mode, etc.)

  - Mapping the keyboard/joystick to screen touch for much better game experience
  - Passing through sensor data (e.g. accelerator) to Android, like Microsoft Surface.
  - GPS location simulation, show up wherever you want
  - File sharing between Windows and Android
  - One click to create/clone Android instances

System Requirements:

- Windows Vista/Windows 7 SP1/Windows 8.1/Windows 10
- Intel or AMD CPU (with Virtualization Technology support preferred)
- GPU with OpenGL 2.0+ support
- At least 1 GB free system memory
- At least 2 GB of free disk space under installation path

...and by the way it's absolutely FREE

Comment: I gave it a try but it's buggy and also in Chinese. Went to settings and saw that language was already set as English, but somehow everything was still in Chinese.

Comment: What? Really?  Did you download the correct software?? Chinese? I can say I am really surprised by your allegations. Tell you what this is the most smooth lightweight emulator I've ever used and there is no Chinese AFAIK . You just have to choose your phone model, Truth is I have never seen any Chinese in this nice emulator

Comment: Comparing to other Android emulators , MEmu provides the highest performance and greatest compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/). It's much lighter then Android Visual Studio Emulator and it's open source.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be free though. I see a trial version and "choose your plan from $136/year".

Comment: @KennyLJ My apologies, I've used this tool for some time and it always been free. Probably they were acquired by some moneymaker moguls.

Comment: Genymotion does require virtual box as well though (although I've not had any problems with the installation being separate, on Mac or Windows). It's always been a paid product for commercial use I think, the free edition was non-comm use. Having said that, I've always found it pretty good, including for native apps using OpenGL.